# System.Net.WebException: Server returned an error: 553 Could not create file. (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: ftp, xamarin.android, connection

I have typed the following code to try to connect the ftp server throught my Xamarin.Android App:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
    client.UploadFile("ftp://XXX", "STOR", textViewCreatedFilePath.Text);
}
```

But I get the following exception:

```
System.Net.WebException: Server returned an error: 553 Could not create file.
```

I am able to connect to the ftp server using the Android browser but why trying to create file gives me that exception.

Comment: The last parameter in UploadFile method should pass the FileName not the FilePath `UploadFile(string address, string method, string fileName)`

Comment: What exactly do you specify in `ftp://XXX`?